# Do I need to ground a service disconnect

Tags: grounding-and-bonding

I installed a double-pole, double-throw 100A service rated disconnect off of a 100A breaker just after the meter to my home. It uses a non-switched neutral bus. I also installed a 50A power inlet on the bottom of the disconnect to which I will connect a generator cord. I have read conflicting statements in other forums as to the sharing of the neutral, some stating it is ok because it is a low voltage single phase supply. I'm looking for answers here about sharing the neutral and also if I should ground the disconnect or bond it to the neutral or both. I have a three cable feed with the neutral bonded to the ground within the main distribution panel inside my home. Does it matter at which point the neutral bond is made - first disconnect or main panel?

Comment: Nothing easier. Your entire system on your side of the meter has >>***ONE***<< place where neutral and ground are bonded to each other.  That is required for the equipotential bond to do its job.  Further, to do that job, it needs to be as close as feasible to the meter, and must not be in cord-and-plug connected equipment.  Keep in mind metal conduit is a grounding path.

Comment: Do you want to use your generator only as a standby generator for the house, or do you want to be able to use it as a portable generator as well?

Comment: I take it your meter's on a pole, for that matter, or is it mounted on the outside of the house?

Comment: Stand by generator only and meter is mounted on a utility tree. Does it matter at which point the neutral bond is made?

Comment: And the generator inlet and switch are next to the meter out on the utility pole?

Comment: That is correct Harper. According to NEC Service disconnecting means [250.24(B)] - Services supplied by a grounded utility transformer must run a grounded (neutral) conductor from the electric utility transformer to each service disconnecting means. [250.28] reads: You must bond the grounded (neutral) conductor from a grounded utility supply to each disconnecting means enclosure (neutral-to-case connection) by a screw or strap supplied by the equipment manufacturer. I'm thinking I need to separate the neutral to frame bond on the generator though.

Comment: @gordo -- is the feeder from the pole to the house run in conduit, as a direct-buried cable, or overhead?

Comment: The service comes in from underground to the meter, the breaker, then the transfer switch, all of which are mounted on the utility tree. There is no pole. From there it enters the home through plastic conduit. I fear too many questions are being asked here than this site allows.

Comment: I believe I have found the answers to my questions in the NEC. Regarding generators: Generators. If the grounded (neutral) conductor in a transfer switch is not opened, the grounded (neutral) from the generator will be solidly connected to the utility’s service grounded (neutral) conductor. Under this condition, the generator isn’t a separately derived system, and a neutral-to-case bond must not be made at the generator or at the generator disconnect [250.20(D) FPN 1].

Comment: @gordo -- you're fine re: question structure, first off :) getting to the meat of things, though -- how big is that conduit, and what gauge are the wires inside it?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel -- as far as I know, bonding practices are not dependent on conduit nor wire size. Thanks to you and Harper but I have found my answer and am no longer in need of continuing this thread.

Comment: @gordo -- the idea behind knowing the conduit and wire size is to figure out if you could pull a grounding wire from the meter location to the house via the existing conduit

Comment: What would be the reason for that?

Comment: @gordo -- separating ground and neutral at all points where they are not explicitly bonded is a *VERY GOOD IDEA* from a safety standpoint

Comment: What does "explicitly bonded" mean? I'm not familiar with that term.

Comment: Seems like among all that there'd be an answer so the question could be resolved.

Comment: @isherwood -- things ran aground when the OP didn't specify enough details about their existing feeder to determine if converting to a 4-wire setup was an option

Comment: Then close votes are in order, I'd say.